# Trying to Reset Column When Another Column Changes Value

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to reset the inning column everytime the pitcher changes and have it be a new column called 'InningBreakdown'

Want to keep the inning breakdown the same, just shift the data when the pitcher changes

```
                pitcher  inning    
2620      Maggie McGurk       0                
2621      Maggie McGurk       0              
2622      Maggie McGurk       0                  
2623      Maggie McGurk       1
2624      Maggie McGurk       1
2625      Maggie McGurk       1
2626      Maggie McGurk       1
2627      Maggie McGurk       1
2628  Kailey Minarchick       1
2629  Kailey Minarchick       1
2630  Kailey Minarchick       1
2631  Kailey Minarchick       1
2632  Kailey Minarchick       1
2633  Kailey Minarchick       3
2634  Kailey Minarchick       4
2635  Kailey Minarchick       4
2636  Kailey Minarchick       4
2637  Kailey Minarchick       5
2638  Kailey Minarchick       6
2639  Kailey Minarchick       7
2640  Kailey Minarchick       8
2641  Kailey Minarchick       8
2642  Kailey Minarchick       9
2643  Kailey Minarchick       9
2644  Kailey Minarchick      10
2645  Kailey Minarchick      11
2646  Kailey Minarchick      12
2647  Kailey Minarchick      12
2648  Kailey Minarchick      12
2649  Kailey Minarchick      12
2650  Kailey Minarchick      12
2651  Kailey Minarchick      12
2652  Kailey Minarchick      13
2653  Kailey Minarchick      13
2654  Kailey Minarchick      13
2655  Kailey Minarchick      13
2656  Kailey Minarchick      13
2657  Kailey Minarchick      13
2658  Kailey Minarchick      13
2659  Kailey Minarchick      13
2660  Kailey Minarchick      13
2661       Leah Allison      13
2662       Leah Allison      13
2663       Leah Allison      13
2664       Leah Allison      14
2665       Leah Allison      15
2666          Erin Hunt      15
2667          Erin Hunt      16
2668          Erin Hunt      17
2669          Erin Hunt      17
2670          Erin Hunt      17
2671          Erin Hunt      18
2672          Erin Hunt      19
2673          Erin Hunt      19
2674          Erin Hunt      20
2675          Erin Hunt       0
2676          Erin Hunt       1
2677          Erin Hunt       1
2678          Erin Hunt       1
2679          Erin Hunt       1
2680          Erin Hunt       1
2681          Erin Hunt       1
2682          Erin Hunt       1
2683          Erin Hunt       1
2684          Erin Hunt       1
2685          Erin Hunt       2
2686          Erin Hunt       3
2687          Erin Hunt       4
```

This is what I want the code to look like, which can include the inning column or not whatever is easier:

```
                pitcher  inningbreakdown
2620      Maggie McGurk       0
2621      Maggie McGurk       0
2622      Maggie McGurk       0
2623      Maggie McGurk       1
2624      Maggie McGurk       1
2625      Maggie McGurk       1
2626      Maggie McGurk       1
2627      Maggie McGurk       1
2628  Kailey Minarchick       0
2629  Kailey Minarchick       0
2630  Kailey Minarchick       0
2631  Kailey Minarchick       0
2632  Kailey Minarchick       0
2633  Kailey Minarchick       2
2634  Kailey Minarchick       3
2635  Kailey Minarchick       3
2636  Kailey Minarchick       3
2637  Kailey Minarchick       4
2638  Kailey Minarchick       5
2639  Kailey Minarchick       6
2640  Kailey Minarchick       7
2641  Kailey Minarchick       7
2642  Kailey Minarchick       8
2643  Kailey Minarchick       8
2644  Kailey Minarchick       9
2645  Kailey Minarchick      10
2646  Kailey Minarchick      11
2647  Kailey Minarchick      11
2648  Kailey Minarchick      11
2649  Kailey Minarchick      11
2650  Kailey Minarchick      11
2651  Kailey Minarchick      11
2652  Kailey Minarchick      12
2653  Kailey Minarchick      12
2654  Kailey Minarchick      12
2655  Kailey Minarchick      12
2656  Kailey Minarchick      12
2657  Kailey Minarchick      12
2658  Kailey Minarchick      12
2659  Kailey Minarchick      12
2660  Kailey Minarchick      12
2661       Leah Allison       0
2662       Leah Allison       0
2663       Leah Allison       0
2664       Leah Allison       1
2665       Leah Allison       2
2666          Erin Hunt       0
2667          Erin Hunt       1
2668          Erin Hunt       2
2669          Erin Hunt       2
2670          Erin Hunt       2
2671          Erin Hunt       3
2672          Erin Hunt       4
2673          Erin Hunt       4
2674          Erin Hunt       5
2675          Erin Hunt       0
2676          Erin Hunt       1
2677          Erin Hunt       1
2678          Erin Hunt       1
2679          Erin Hunt       1
2680          Erin Hunt       1
2681          Erin Hunt       1
2682          Erin Hunt       1
2683          Erin Hunt       1
2684          Erin Hunt       1
2685          Erin Hunt       2
2686          Erin Hunt       3
2687          Erin Hunt       4
```

Comment: your output and input are identical. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Edited just now, the output and input should be different now

Answer (score 0):

You need create inning and inningbreakdown columns. Set inningbreakdown is None at start. And when pitcher changes, copy value from inning to inningbreakdown.

Comment: This is a hint at an answer, not an actual answer. I'd rather leave such instructions as a comment, once you have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Do you have an answer cs95?